# Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing (Competing Risks with CFC package)

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indexing, survival-analysis

I would like to use the [CFC package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CFC/CFC.pdf) on R.

So, I start with the function *cfc.prepdata*:

```
cfc.prepdata(Surv(mydata$T, mydata$status) ~ mydata$age + mydata$score, mydata)
```

With **T** my time vector, **status** the one which takes values from 0 to 4 (I have 4 competing risks).

I get the error message: 
**Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing**

I did everything like explained in the CFC package PDF, I know something is wrong about the "dat" part of :

```
cfc.prepdata(formul, dat)
```

but I don't understand what and why.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is mydata a tibble by any chance? If so, try converting mydata to a data.frame via as.data.frame(). I've had this same error in the Caret package when using tibbles.

Comment: You should not  use `mydata$` at all in the formula since the `data` argument has that information. It often creates later problems because the source of the data will not be "remembered" as coming from `mydata` (strange as that may seem).